# 'boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp' file not found ERROR

Tags: c++, boost, gnuplot

I'm trying to call gnuplot from C++ and I've included the gnuplot-iostream.h library and the boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp library in the same directory as my source code, but I still get the error that the directory is not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you include the headers in your code? If `file_descriptor.hpp` is in your source directory but you `#include "boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp"` you might get that error.

Comment: Also, rather than copying header files into your source directory it is usually preferable to tell the compiler where to look in the system directories, e.g. `$COMPILER -I /usr/include`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct include delimiters?

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
```

will search the specified library search paths (including the compiler implicits).

```
#include "boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp"
```

will search relative to the current translation unit too.

---

If this was the cause, you could

- change the delimiter style (recommended)
- add "." to the library include paths